# How to configurate a servlet path in web.xml

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am stuck into a problem i cannot find a solution to solve it. I've wrote an multi-tier application in Java(build: maven, deployed:jboss 6/tomcat, db: oracle 10g) and now try to develope a presentation layer with jsp (ServiceBeans/Servlets). So far this all works fine.

I now wanted to surround the jsp-Views with a SecurityWrapper.. and here's my prob:

1. the authentification with the Jboss "other" realm works:

[image: jboss file directory]

(after mananging this with a local file, it's planned to make an ldap request on the AD)

2. configurating the security-constraint and login-config in the web.xml and creating a jboss-web.xml file all works fine
3. Problem: while putting the Views under a "protected" folder and restricting the access with my constraint, i am just getting the "empty" html stuff out of the view and not the requested sql output... ooooorrr i am ending up in an continuous sql-statement loop in the jboss console :( :(

And i have **NO** clue about how the paths have to be set up in the servlet/web.xml and index.jsp. There are tons of Tutorials, but i was not able to find any solution to my sql-loop. (memo: worked fine, while there was no folder the views were put into)

Here are refering abstract code snippets:

Project PATH (in Eclipse):
[image: path in eclipse]

WEB.XML:

```
      <!-- SERVLET MAPPING -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>EmplDataServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>de.xxx.xxx.web.EmplDataServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <!-- SERVLET MAPPINGS -->
  <servlet-name>EmplDataServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/protected/EmplDataServlet.jsp</url-pattern>   (continuous sql loop)
 </servlet-mapping>
 <!-- WELCOME FILES -->
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <!-- SECURITY -->
 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>auth-pages</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
 <!-- LOGIN -->
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>other</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/ErrPage.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
 <!-- ROLLE -->
 <security-role>
  <role-name>admin</role-name>
 </security-role>
</web-app>
```

EmplDataServlet:  `getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/protected/EmplDataView.jsp")
                    .forward(request, response);`

Index.jsp: `<a class="nav" href="EmplDataView" target="contentFrame">Empl Data</a>`

Please bear with my weak english skills - i've tried my best!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your security settings but do you see the right output when security is turned off?

Comment: very nice hint!! Putting the view i wanted to secure back to /* == works fine. Putting the view into a new folder and setting the security constraint on that one == works fine...Putting the view back to the /protected folder, and setting the secur.constr. on this == continuous sql looping in the jboss console. I don't know WHAT exactly the matter is, but using a new created folder works excellent... -.-'  Thank you very much for the hint though, without you i would have never gave it a try :)