# Servlet is not executing

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

I have a program that writes new employee information to a text file. I have a project in which I must adapt said program into one that inputs that info into an Oracle database instead. I put in the info and hit the submit button, then nothing happens, not even an error message or thrown exception. I have no idea what is wrong or where to even start looking, and I can admit that I am in a little bit over my head here. I am fairly certain the problem lies with the servlet, somehow. Here is my code:

form.jsp:

```
<%@page session="false" import="java.util.Iterator"%>

<%-- Retrieve the Status bean from the Request scope --%>
<jsp:useBean id="status" scope="request" class="util.Status"/>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Project 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Employee Hiring Form</h1>

        <%-- Display any errors from previous form submission. --%>
        <c:if test="${!status.isSuccessful}">
            <font color="red">There were problems processing your request:      
                <ul>
                    <c:forEach var="ex" items="${status.exceptions}">
                        <li>
                            <c:out value="${ex.message}"></c:out>
                        </li>
                    </c:forEach>        
                </ul>
            </font>    
        </c:if>

        <%-- Display the form to enter a new hire. --%>
        <form     action="C:\Users\Nelle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EmployeeDB\src\java\web\HiringServlet" method="POST">
            <label for="department"><strong>Department</strong></label><br />
            <select name="department">
                <%String department = request.getParameter("department"); if (department == null) {department = "";}%>     
                <option value="unknown" <%if(department.equals("unknown")){out.print(" selected");}%>>Select a department...</s:option>
                <option value="Human Resources" <%if(department.equals("Human Resources")){out.print(" selected");}%>>Human Resources</s:option>
                <option value="Software Development" <%if(department.equals("Software Development")){out.print(" selected");}%>>Software Development</s:option>
                <option value="Media Relations" <%if(department.equals("Media Relations")){out.print(" selected");}%>>Media Relations</s:option>
            </select><br /><br />

            <%String name = request.getParameter("name");if (name==null) name="";%>
            <label for="name"><strong>Employee Name</strong></label><br />
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=name%>" /><br /><br />

            <%String jobTitle = request.getParameter("jobTitle");if (jobTitle == null) jobTitle = "";%>
            <label for="jobTitle"><strong>Job Title</strong></label><br />
            <input type="text" name="jobTitle" value="<%=jobTitle%>" /><br /><br />

            <%String yearHired = request.getParameter("yearHired");if (yearHired == null) yearHired = "";%>
            <label for="yearHired"><strong>Year Hired</strong></label><br />
            <input type="text" name="yearHired" value="<%=yearHired%>" /><br /><br />

            <%String gender = request.getParameter("gender");if (gender == null) gender = "";%>
            <label for="gender"><strong>Gender</strong></label><br />
            <input type="text" name="gender" value="<%=gender%>" /><br /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Add Employee" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

confirmation.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="department" scope="request" class="domain.Department"/>
<jsp:useBean id="employee" scope="request" class="domain.Employee"/>
<jsp:useBean id="hiringList" scope="request" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Project 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New Hire Successfully Added</h1>
        <p>
            <strong>Employee Information</strong><br /><br />
            Name: <jsp:getProperty name="employee" property="name"/><br />
            Job Title: <jsp:getProperty name="employee" property="jobTitle"/><br />
            Year Hired: <jsp:getProperty name="employee" property="yearHired"/><br />
            Gender: <jsp:getProperty name="employee" property="gender"/><br /><br />

            Added to department: <jsp:getProperty name="department" property="name"/><br />
        </p>

        <form action="form.jsp" method="POST" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Another Employee" name="more" />
        </form>

        <hr />

        <h2>Complete Employee List</h2>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Name</td><td>Job Title</td><td>Year Hired</td><td>Gender</td>    <td>Department</td><td>Department Description</td></tr>
            <c:forEach var="hire" items="${hiringList}">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:0 15px 0 5px;"><c:out value="${hire.getEmployee().getName()}"></c:out></td>
                    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:0 15px 0 5px;"><c:out value="${hire.getEmployee().getJobTitle()}"></c:out></td>
                    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:0 15px 0 5px;"><c:out value="${hire.getEmployee().getYearHired()}"></c:out></td>
                    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:0 15px 0 5px;"><c:out value="${hire.getEmployee().getGender()}"></c:out></td>
                    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:0 15px 0 5px;"><c:out value="${hire.getDepartment().getName()}"></c:out></td>
                    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:0 15px 0 5px;"><c:out value="${hire.getDepartment().getDescription()}"></c:out></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

HiringServlet.java:

```
(imports removed)

public class HiringServlet extends HttpServlet {

public Statement statement;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        //Declare the dispatcher for the View
        RequestDispatcher view = null; 

        //Create the business logic object
        HiringService hs = null;

        //Create the Status object and store it in the request 
        //for use by the 'Registration Form' View (if necessary)
        Status status = new Status();
        request.setAttribute("status", status);

        //Retrieve the HTML form parameters
        String departmentName = request.getParameter("department");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String jobTitle = request.getParameter("jobTitle");
        String yearHired = request.getParameter("yearHired");
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");

        // Verify form fields data; create Exception objects if data are missing
        if (departmentName.equals("unknown")) 
            status.addException(new Exception("Please select a department. "));
        if ((name == null) || (name.length() == 0))
            status.addException(new Exception("Please enter the employee name. "));
        if ((jobTitle == null) || (jobTitle.length() == 0))
            status.addException(new Exception("Please enter the job title. "));
        if ((yearHired == null) || (yearHired.length() == 0))
            status.addException(new Exception("Please enter the year hired. "));
        if ((gender == null) || (gender.length() == 0))
            status.addException(new Exception("Please enter the gender. "));

        // In case of errors, forward the request back to 'Registration Form' 
        // View and return without proceeding with the rest of the business logic.
        if(!status.isSuccessful()){
            view = request.getRequestDispatcher("form.jsp");              
            view.forward(request, response);
            return;
        }

        //If no verification errors are found, the Controller
        //uses the business services to perform the registration.
        try {

      // Load the JDBC driver
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      System.out.println("Driver loaded");

      // Establish a connection
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@nova.umuc.edu:1521:acad", "username", "password");
      System.out.println("Database connected");

      // Create a statement
      statement = connection.createStatement();

            hs = new HiringService();

            // Retrieve the department object and verify that it exists.
            Department department = hs.getDepartment(departmentName);

            if (department == null) throw new Exception("The department you have "+
               " selected does not yet exist; please select another one.");

            //Create and populate the employee object
            Employee employee = hs.createEmployee(
                name, jobTitle, yearHired, gender);

            //Delegate hiring to the HiringService object.
            Hiring newHire = new Hiring(employee, department);
            hs.hire(newHire);

            ArrayList hiringList = hs.getHirings();

            request.setAttribute( "department", department);
            request.setAttribute( "employee", employee);
            request.setAttribute( "hiringList", hiringList);

            // Select the next View for the user in case hiring is 
            // successful Forward to the confirmation.jsp View       
            view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/confirmation.jsp");         
            view.forward(request,response);
        } 

        catch (Exception ex){
            status.addException(ex);

            //Select next View.
            //Exceptions are caught, forward back to the form.jsp View.  
            view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/form.jsp");           
            view.forward(request,response);
        }

        finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to see any of my other .java documents, let me know and I'll post them, but I don't think they're the problem.

Comment: Where is `HiringServlet.class` deployed? Is it really below `src`?

Comment: Actually, I moved HiringServlet to <default package> and now it submits. I know you're not supposed to do that, but it's the only thing that worked. Now I just have to work on getting the confirmation page to display :/

Comment: With package you just need a proper directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from here

```
<form action="C:\Users\Nelle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EmployeeDB\src\java\web\HiringServlet" method="POST">
```

Do you have any clue about your *HiringServlet* being called?

Comment: That line was already there in the program I was given as a starting point, except I changed it to include the full directory (C:\Users etc) because it was giving me an error without it. Before, if read: action="HiringServlet"

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Servlet in web.xml and give the url pattern  in "form" tag in "action" attribute.

Look at the link.

[How to configurate a servlet path in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871139/how-to-configurate-a-servlet-path-in-web-xml)